# PHP - Excluding blank rows when printing a table

Tags: php

The code below works great.  It prints out items in a MySQL database as an HTML table.  However, the database has entries where the first column (the variable "site") is blank.  How can I have this table exclude rows / entries where "site" is blank?

```
$result=mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM database LIKE '$find'")
or die(mysql_error());


if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
while($table=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
print "<p class=\"topic\">$table[0]</p>\n";
$r=mysql_query("SELECT * , itemsa - itemsb AS itemstotal FROM `$table[0]` ORDER BY itemstotal DESC");



print "<table class=\"navbar\">\n";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)){


$itemstotal = $row['itemsa'] - $row['itemsb']; 

print "<tr>";


print "<td class='sitename'>".'<a type="amzn" category="books" class="links2">'.$row['site'].'</a>'."</td>";

print "<td class='class1'>".'<span class="class1_count" id="class1_count'.$row['id'].'">'.number_format($itemstotal).'</span>'."</td>";
print "<td class='selector'>".'<span class="button" id="button'.$row['id'].'">'.'<a href="javascript:;" class="cell1" id="'.$row['id'].'">'.Select.'</a>'.'</span>'."</td>";
}
print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";



}
else{
print "";
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a where clause to the SQL query.

```
WHERE `site` <> ''
or
WHERE `site` != ''
```

should work.

However, if you want the rows where site is blank for other PHP options, it would be better to filter out the blank sites in the PHP and not the MySQL query.

Comment: Duh, me.  I like this *much* better than my own solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the following before the `print` calls in your `while` loop:

```
if (trim($row['site']) == '') {
    // skip output of this row if site is empty
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to insert the following line into your inner `while` block:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)){

if (!trim($row['site'])) continue; // skip empty rows

$itemstotal = $row['itemsa'] - $row['itemsb'];
```

**Edit:** Actually, it looks like that `$itemstotal` variable isn't needed; it's being calculated as a "virtual" `itemstotal` column in the SQL query.  If you replace "`number_format($itemstotal)`" with "`number_format($row['itemstotal'])`" a few lines down, you can get rid of the "`$itemstotal = ...`" line entirely.

Comment: Gumbo is right, you cannot use empty(trim($foo)). It will not work: http://www.php.net/empty

Comment: @Gumbo, Abinadi — Clearly, my PHP-fu is getting weaker; fixed.  @tharkun — Comment spam is bad, mmmk?

Comment: but this is just hilarious guys! sorry for comment spam if you think it is... but the comment is indeed true at evey post I wrote it...

Answer (score 0):

```
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)){
if($row['site'] != "") {
    $itemstotal = $row['itemsa'] - $row['itemsb']; 
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td class='sitename'>".'<a type="amzn" category="books" class="links2">'.$row['site'].'</a>'."</td>";
    print "<td class='class1'>".'<span class="class1_count" id="class1_count'.$row['id'].'">'.number_format($itemstotal).'</span>'."</td>";
    print "<td class='selector'>".'<span class="button" id="button'.$row['id'].'">'.'<a href="javascript:;" class="cell1" id="'.$row['id'].'">'.Select.'</a>'.'</span>'."</td>";
}
}
```